# NetSuite: Difference between dates Excluding weekends for transaction formula

Tags: oracle, netsuite

Hi I need a formula that will give me the difference in working days `(M,T,W,Th)` between two dates. So in other words just excluding weekends.

My current formula is: `ROUND({systemnotes.date}-{trandate})`
This works great except for that it counts Saturday and Sunday.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a formula that will get you the difference between two dates excluding Saturday and Sunday as a number of days. Put this into a formula(numeric) field in your search.

```
ROUND(((TO_CHAR({systemnotes.date}, 'J') - TO_CHAR({trandate}, 'J'))) + MOD(({systemnotes.date} - {trandate}), 1) - ((((TRUNC({systemnotes.date}, 'D')) - (TRUNC({trandate}, 'D')))/7)*2) - (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR({trandate}, 'DY') = 'SUN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR({systemnotes.date}, 'DY') = 'SAT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 2)
```

Sorry, it's a bit of a long one, but in the formula `{systemnotes.date}` is your start date and `{trandate}` is your end date.